# TypeError 'thing' is undefined, with javascript instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

So I'm having an issue with javascript objects, and accessing functions inside instantiations.  Here's what I got in my main code. I instantiate an IFU object.  Inside the initialization of that object, I instantiate a Dapqa object and assign it to a variable, ifu.dapqa = new Dapqa().  I have a submit button on a form that is bound to a function addComments onclick. This function is a function a part of my Dapqa object.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/ifu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/dapqa.js"></script>
<script type='type/javascript'>
  var ifu = {};
  $(function() {
    var ifuid = $('.galinfo').attr('id');
    ifu = new Ifu(ifuid);
    ifu.print();
    ifu.dapqa.print();
    ifu.dapqa.addComments('submit'); //test
  });
</script>

<body>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' id='dapqasubmit' onclick='ifu.dapqa.addComments("submit")'>Submit</button>
</body>
```

I then check things by running some test print functions in each class.  I'm also testing a call to a function addComments on the Dapqa object.  This function looks like

```
Dapqa.prototype.addComments = function(action) {
    console.log('adding comments',action);
};
```

When I load the page, the console output looks good to me.

```
We are now printing ifu  9101
We are now printing dapqa info:  9101 sampletab
adding comments submit
```

However, when I click the Submit button on my form, I get the error

```
TypeError: ifu.dapqa is undefined
```

Now I thought I solved this by declaring ifu as a global variable, which then gets populated once the page finishes loading, but apparently not.  The weird thing is that this works perfectly fine for another function inside my Dapqa object.  I have a separate function

```
 Dapqa.prototype.loadImageModal = function(img) {
    var src = $('#'+img).attr('src');
    var name = src.slice(src.search('manga-'));
    this.imagemodaltitle.html(name);
    var image = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="'+src+'" alt="Image"/>';
    this.imagemodalbody.html(image);
};
```

and I also call this from an anchor point inside my html, e.g.

```
<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#dapimgmodal_9101' onclick='ifu.dapqa.loadImageModal("mapsimgs1_9101")'><img src="" class="img-responsive img-rounded" id='mapsimg1_9101' alt="Image"></a>
```

This part of the code works just fine.  So I don't understand why one function is defined but the other is not.  Any thoughts on this?

**Update** 
It seems to be a problem with my buttons.  I tried it with an anchor point and it seems to work.

```
<a type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' id='daptestsubmit' onclick='ifu.dapqa.addComments("submit")'>TestSubmit</a>
```

I have no idea why though.  Any idea why anchors work but not buttons?  I'm using Boostrap 3.3.2.

Comment: Seems to work fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/p3rpL5wj/

Comment: that's really weird.  It doesn't work for me.  I've restarted the browser and cleared the cache.  No change.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why it wouldn't work for me?

Comment: If the JSFiddle example I posted works for you, then there's information missing from the question. If it doesn't work, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yeah the JsFiddle does work for me.  I've tried it in both Chrome and Firefox and it fails in both.  I'm not sure what information could be missing.  I simplified the example a bit in terms of the html layout.  Since it's in a Flask webapp, the html is layered in a bunch of jinja2 templates and macros.  I don't think that would matter though, because it all gets rendered together in the end.

Comment: Apparently it's an issue with the button.  I tried an anchor: <a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' id='daptestsubmit' onclick='ifu.dapqa.addComments("submit")'>TestSubmit</a> and this worked just fine.  But why doesn't the button work when it works in the JSFiddle?  Your button is the same as my button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the order of your scripts ifu.js and dapqa.js declaration. As dapqa.js apparently depend on ifu.js, it should be loaded first like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/dapqa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/ifu.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that.  I switched them so they now have the correct order but that didn't solve the problem. :(